# How to know whether the amount is deducted from card or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, xcode6, stripe-payments

I am using `stripe+parse` to make payment.

I am passing the token value to the `Parse` `Cloud` `Code` and making Payment.

Currently I am using `test` keys.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {

var stripe = require('stripe');
stripe.initialize('sk_test_lLGvnjknjknjknjknjknjkn51H3gG ');

var stripeToken = request.params.token;

var charge = stripe.Charges.create({
 amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
currency: "usd",
 source: stripeToken,
description: "payinguser@example.com"
 }, function(err, charge) {
if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
// The card has been declined
}
});

  response.success(charge);

 });
```

When I tun this code And  the Charge variable, I get the following response:

```
Cloud Code: {
"_rejected" = 0;
"_rejectedCallbacks" =     (
);
"_resolved" = 0;
"_resolvedCallbacks" =     (
);
}
```

How can I know that the amount is deducted.

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseStore/blob/master/CloudTest/cloud/main.js

Comment: when i try to build the project i am getting linker errors.. i have set all the keys